# The windows installation tool ( WINE )

Tags: installation, windows, wine, boot-partition

If I use the tool on the hard drive where windows is installed will it damage the windows OS or will it create a new partition ?

Comment: using WINE will not affect windows. What is it you are doing exactly ?

Comment: He probably means "wubi".

Answer (score 1):

Wine is a Linux application totally independent from Windows. It won't affect Windows at all.

If on the other hand you're talking of WUBI, this is a Windows program that installs Ubuntu like any other Windows program and it can be installed and uninstalled like other Windows programs.